# C++ template instantiation with if statements

Tags: c++

I wanna write a `sort` function that takes variadic parameters containing several containers: `void sort(C &c, Rest&... rest)`;

```
template<typename T>
struct is_list{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_list<std::list<T>>{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_list<std::forward_list<T>>{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<typename C, typename...Rest>
void sort(C &c, Rest&... rest){
    if(is_list<C>::value == true) c.sort(); 
    else std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
    sort(rest...);
}

//main file
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
sort(vec);
```

**Two errors:**

1. vector has no member named 'sort' of `if(is_list<C>::value == true) c.sort();`

but logically if statement should not execute since I pass a vector, not a list.

2. no matching function for call to 'sort()' of `sort(rest...);`

Second error is obvious, but what's the reason for error 1.

**And I solved it by**

```
template<typename T>
struct is_list{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_list<std::list<T>>{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_list<std::forward_list<T>>{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<typename C, typename std::enable_if<!is_list<C>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void sort(C &c){
    sort(c.begin(), c.end());
}

template<typename C, typename std::enable_if<is_list<C>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void sort(C &c){
    c.sort();
}   

template<typename C, typename...Rest>
void sort(C &c, Rest&... rest){
    sort(c);
    sort(rest...);
}
```

Comment: Look up `if constexpr` in C++17 or later.   Otherwise, you need to explicitly specialise your `sort()` function for different container types, rather than trying to do a runtime test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error comes from the fact that at the time the compiler instantiates your template, it compiles the whole function, not just the `if` branch that satisfies the condition.

It means that when you're passing a vector to `sort`, it's instantiated with `C` as `std::vector`, but then tries to compile (n.b.: not execute), `c.sort()` anyway. And in this case, `std::vector` has no `sort()` member. This is why you get this error. Because the compiler will try to instantiate the whole template (i.e. replace `C` by the actual type and compile every single line).

To fix it, you need to rework your template so it instantiate a version which fully compile for your types. `std::enable_if` would be a potential solution here:

```
template<typename C, typename std::enable_if<is_list<C>::value>::type >
void sort(C &c){
    c.sort();
}

template<typename C, typename std::enable_if<!is_list<C>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void sort(C &c){
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e2aa1a0a591a8b1)

Comment: yep, that's how i solved it, but your code seems a little problem: the second sort should be: `template<typename C, typename std::enable_if<!is_list<C>::value>::type* = nullptr>` or it will be ambiguous for list

Comment: Beware, `void*` is not a proper non-type template argument. You should really stick ton int.

Comment: @YSC Learnt something new today. Do you know its reason and why compilers never complain?

Comment: @YSC Got it https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-discussion/26jBWYIBrp0/o74AWYXMWpMJ

Comment: @Tartarus Ah right, my bad, I was a bit too quick with this one.

Answer (score 1):

your code had an other issue once you soved the one you saw
you didn't not handle the terminal case of recursion
i also added perfect forwarding

if you are using c++17 you can use constexpr if like

```
template<typename C, typename...Rest>
void sort(C &c, Rest&& ... rest){
    if constexpr (is_list<C>::value == true) c.sort(); 
    else std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
    if constexpr (sizeof...(rest) >= 1) // empty case
        sort(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}
```

else you can use template specialization, overloading or even SFINEA
but i think overloading is the easiest way with c++11

```
//handleing empty case for terminal recursion
void sort() {} 

//list case
template<typename T, typename...Rest>
void sort(std::list<T>& c, Rest&& ... rest){
    c.sort();
    sort(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);

}

//forward list case
template<typename T, typename...Rest>
void sort(std::forward_list<T>& c, Rest&& ... rest){
    c.sort();
    sort(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);

}

//other containers case
template<typename C, typename...Rest>
void sort(C&& c, Rest&& ... rest) {
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
    sort(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}
```